# Multi-stage Docker Build with Node and Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm attempting to create a Dockerfile for a custom image that can be used in a pipeline job. I would like for the image in the first stage to be node and the image in the second stage to be ubuntu. This is what I currently have. When I run the container interactively, I'm able to use the "node" command. However, when I enter "npm" I get the following error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/cli.js'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/bin/npm
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:873:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/bin/npm:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/usr/local/bin/npm' ]
}
```

Here is the code that I used for my Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1: Node.js/npm stage
FROM node:16 AS node
WORKDIR /app
# Stage 2: ubuntu stage
FROM ubuntu 

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Node.js/npm components from the Node.js/npm stage
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/
```

I'm expecting for the "npm" command to return a list of npm options or at least show me the version when I enter npm --version.

Comment: Why you don't install nodejs and npm directly on ubuntu? `RUN apt update && apt install nodejs && apt install npm`

Comment: Thank you @Max. I think that's what I'll end up doing. I apologize if it was a basic question, but I didn't realize node and npm could be installed used the apt command.

Answer (score 1):

There is more to Node.JS than the `node` binary.  The error message you're seeing is that it expects to be finding its runtime libraries in `/usr/local/lib`, but you haven't copied them into the image.

Unless you know that a program is a single static binary (which is unusual) it can be very hard to `COPY` a program from one Docker image to another.  You're prone to missing things like runtime support files, configuration files, and Linux shared libraries.

Given the Dockerfile you show, there's no particular reason to try to reinstall the Docker-derived Node in a plain-Ubuntu image. Just build your application image `FROM node`, as in this generic Node-application Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM node:lts
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY ./ ./
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

If you need to compile a front-end application to static files, use this in combination with a multi-stage build.  If you need to interactively run `npm` then you'll probably find it vastly easier to just install Node on the host without involving Docker at all.

Comment: Thank you. I think installing node on the host is a much easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still need this variant, it *may* work with `COPY --from=node / /` directive, i.e. just merging 2 filesystems. I had a project which could not install any software via apt (or any other external source) at Jenkins stage, so the only option was to reuse NPM/NODE from step 1.

Obviously, it may have compatibility issues if you have different basic volumes for two images.